# How to fix "free(): double free detected in tcache 2" error?

Tags: c++

So, I have created a derived class template called unorderedSet that uses a pointer member variable to hold the location of an array on the heap (using new).

I am trying to overload the arithmetic operators to find both the intersection and union of two different unorderedSet objects, and the code I have written so far (with the help of another user on this site) manages that. However, upon running the program I get the error in the title. I will post the relevant parts of my code below.

```
template <class elemType>
class unorderedSet: public unorderedArrayListType<elemType>
{
public:
  void insertAt(int location, const elemType& insertItem);
  void insertEnd(const elemType& insertItem);
  void replaceAt(int location, const elemType& repItem);
  const unorderedSet<elemType> operator+(const unorderedSet<elemType>&);
  // Function to overload the binary operator + to find the union of a pair/group of sets
  // Postcondition: Finds the union of the sets

  const unorderedSet<elemType> operator-(const unorderedSet<elemType>&);
  // Function to overload the binary operator - to find the intersection of a pair/group of sets
  // Postcondition: Finds the intersection of the sets
  
  unorderedSet(int size = 100);
  unorderedSet(const unorderedSet<elemType>& otherSet);
  ~unorderedSet();
  
protected:
  elemType *set;
  int length;
  int maxSize;
};

template <class elemType>
const unorderedSet<elemType> unorderedSet<elemType>::operator+(const unorderedSet<elemType>& otherSet)
{
  unorderedSet<elemType> unSet(this->length + otherSet.length); // Initializes new set to hold values of the union set

  for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
    unSet.insertEnd(this->list[i]); // Assigns all values of the activating operand to the union set using insertEnd
  
  for (int i = 0; i < otherSet.length; i++)
    unSet.insertEnd(otherSet.list[i]); // Calls insertEnd() to both check for duplicate values and add unique values to the union of the sets

  return unSet; // Should return the union set, but dumps the core at the moment
} // end operator overload

template <class elemType>
unorderedSet<elemType>::unorderedSet(int size) : unorderedArrayListType<elemType>(size)
{
  if (size <= 0)
  {
    cout << "The array size must be positive. Creating an array of the size 100. " << endl;

    this->maxSize = 100;
  }
  else
    this->maxSize = size;

    this->length = 0;

    set = new elemType[this->maxSize];
}

template <class elemType>
unorderedSet<elemType>::~unorderedSet()
{
  delete [] set;
}

template <class elemType>
unorderedSet<elemType>::unorderedSet(const unorderedSet<elemType>& otherSet)
{
  this->maxSize = otherSet.maxSize;
  this->length = otherSet.length;

  set = new elemType[this->maxSize];

  for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    set[j] = otherSet.set[j];
}
```

The following code comes from my test client program.

```
int main() 
{
  int intArr1[6] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  unorderedSet<int> testIntSet1;

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(intArr1) / sizeof(intArr1[0])); i++)
    testIntSet1.insertEnd(intArr1[i]);
  // Some more code before the function call
  
  int intArr2[6] = {0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9};
  unorderedSet<int> testIntSet2, testIntSet3;

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(intArr2) / sizeof(intArr2[0])); i++)
    testIntSet2.insertEnd(intArr2[i]);

  testIntSet3 = testIntSet1 + testIntSet2;
  // Some more code
}
```

I also have an assignment operator overload function in the base class of this class's base class. The code is as follows

```
template <class elemType>
const arrayListType<elemType>& arrayListType<elemType>::operator= (const arrayListType<elemType>& otherList)
{
  if (this != &otherList)    //avoid self-assignment
  {
    delete [] list;
    this->maxSize = otherList.maxSize;
    this->length = otherList.length;
 
    list = new elemType[this->maxSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
      list[i] = otherList.list[i];
  }

  return *this;
}
```

I have attempted to create another version of this in my unorderedSet class, but when I run it the testIntSet3 variable outputs nothing (not even some random garbage). I decided to remove it since the code seemed to at least function properly before.

Comment: If you are running on a Linux system, try `valgrind`.

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. It's almost always a rule of three violation when you have raw pointers

Comment: Rule of 3 violation.  Your `unorderedSet` is not safely copyable or assignable, yet you are doing that.  Right here: `const unorderedSet<elemType> operator-` and here: `const unorderedSet<elemType> operator+`.  The assignment operator, which you totally left out, should not be an afterthought (although it is easily implemented).

Comment: I figured it had something to do with the rule of 3, but I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong. I believed that I was making deep copies in my program with the copy constructor and base class's assignment operator overload, is that not the case @PaulMcKenzie?

Comment: That assignment operator is for `arrayListType`, not `unorderedSet`.  FYI, even that implementation is faulty for a variety of reasons.   For example, you've deleted your `list`, before you know if `new[]` will be successful.  If `new[]` throws an exception, you've messed up your object.  Consider using [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), instead of what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your `orderedSet` is missing the user-defined assignment operator:

```
template <class elemType>
class unorderedSet: public unorderedArrayListType<elemType>
{
  public:
      unorderedSet<elemType>& operator=(const unorderedSet<elemType>&);
  //...
};
```

That function needs to be implemented.  The simplest way to do that, assuming you have a fully functional, working, copy constructor and destructor for `unorderedSet`, would be the following:

```
template <class elemType>
unorderedSet<elemType>& unorderedSet<elemType>::operator=(const unorderedSet<elemType>& otherSet)
{
   if (this != &otherSet)
   {
      unorderedSet<elemType> temp = otherSet;
      std::swap(temp.set, set);
      std::swap(temp.length, length);
      std::swap(temp.maxSize, maxSize);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

This uses the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Your `arrayListType`'s assignment operator should be written in the same fashipn.

Comment: The copy to `temp` can be shifted into the function parameter by declaring the parameter  to take a copy rather than as a `const &`. The test for self-assignment is an unnecessary expense, since you are testing for a rare case all the time, and the modification of the parameter makes it pointless. Finally, add `using std::swap;` inside the function body, and then call `swap` instead of `std::swap` to allow ADL to choose a more type specific `swap` implementation if it is available.

Comment: I have implemented your code, but now I have the issue where the return of the `operator+` function is nothing. I know that means my destructor/copy constructor aren't working properly. My code just seems to be a mess at the moment, but I'll continue tinkering with it until I find something

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate how `valgrind` can be used to diagnose this issue, I converted your program into a more minimal example ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVZNb9s4EL3rVwxaILAaJbGdNotKjoGi2AIBelggvRk@0BJtMyuTWpJyNzXcv56dISVLsmMn3eYScWY4n@8NnRbFxSJNn57eCpnmZcZhJJSxmrPVOGhkpRW5sI/jICiNkAswNovjVJU2aQu4zPIkCCxfFTmzeC3NmTHAc7769ljwMVrpMrVQSqUzrnn2SWv2@FUYS2rYBHBE1RPSwi30Q9hs0ah2CDnqJ4NpEmyTl6Oyg2BdyRmogmtmlb7tdTV6aUJ3gf5a9ZrvrEgqMX333tmlMJGzr@Wa21JLcBqSbSnX48kG/rxrwz23MRTlLBfpkd6MmrubwFvGGGetRAZCGq7tnzLrpUoauwtzVmnuMI/QtdTr22Ebv7u@nPdOmZ25mq@u4EspUyuUBKtArbnOFcvALjnMhGT6cecOzsliLqTXlpLuqDkwKJjQVwutyoLOhlvjPf@F0MQUMkHuY/iCV033Lh2cfRtLmKZDkBE/OMJo0O@7VDv6k5WBQr8aZe7ez85FFAWFVpanlmdxG53vMBGyp9A5lwu7rE8r9u895pK8hIVTQ3leHMevHFZTUrDZ60UnCJVI2L0Y@xJwaPXNSy8JExrNncShsByrMiD5dxoCTXep8gzWLC9RXI3Hzwr1NKM5wsDNRhC/E/w3gnY4lJyfh45LLpfLBtKVGa0AMfVJfDJGLKQBlud7QRkics0sUdc1iDCnuulUzN4FOJbeXvknMmws20l@xuxMi5ohZTJDW0iXPP3bxczKAnlMoKjKoIRZllG2/5Q7aaeEPfRXi8fl5OLeL1WJw6jkndIjmJUWg64KT6dUaWyZdd8rteLSBltygQu@YW9N7VMIPgbSZ6kZQvzijus5QwdZMQd3gpF/GdwI6E2C0QjefKOhkw/P@lWJVJhxKJRBnK75JXzGN87hgcnKsG4g2eOOuIQ35Mk/auTbA67irt8jfqMT5w0/0BtH8QA6gHY4QhkB7tYxpa5t0rlPj9r/6ezecnKdylCPPiZTcBtp@9sT@5XNst@VHSl2S/CgQfsMC17XrzZfHzxfH5CvNU0fapqiq8nDtB3HS1xn/HoWsmqd4760iMbB5IbubPoRDCIYRnAdwfsIPmz3n5IR2o/BcmPvpMXzIDm2SRx81bxXBQjhCrqSSX8ahq0F03LaWjO1MS0Y/07eI2eRuJqYjD/fZnxO3wTuef02p7iFgk6Bw06BWN1NBH9E8PHFArEXzeH6ldUOD6odHq92eFDt0FcbtK2uMVarQ/TzovHwbGeC7dPTfw)).

When I run valgrind against the program (compiled as `g++ -g x.cpp`), there is output that reads:

> <sup><sub>`==598== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()`
>
> `==598==    at 0x4C3373B: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108E78: unorderedSet<int>::~unorderedSet() (x.cpp:68)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108CC7: main (x.cpp:93)`
>
> `==598==  Address 0x5b80630 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 400 free'd`
>
> `==598==    at 0x4C3373B: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108E78: unorderedSet<int>::~unorderedSet() (x.cpp:68)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108CBB: main (x.cpp:98)`
>
> `==598==  Block was alloc'd at`
>
> `==598==    at 0x4C3289F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108E40: unorderedSet<int>::unorderedSet(int) (x.cpp:62)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108ECC: unorderedSet<int>::operator+(unorderedSet<int> const&) (x.cpp:41)`
>
> `==598==    by 0x108C97: main (x.cpp:98)`</sub></sup>

The `valgrind` output is saing that the address being freed points inside an already freed block. Hence, the issue is a ***double free***.

Helpfully, it locates the two distinct locations of the double free.

> `93   unorderedSet<int> testIntSet2, testIntSet3;`

and

> `98   testIntSet3 = testIntSet1 + testIntSet2;`

The second free is detected on line 93, so the first one occurred on line 98. We deduce the destruction is from the temporary returned by `operator+`.

Since the destruction was not expected to trigger a double free, your hypothesis is that the copy was not deep for some reason, and the same pointer was used in the copy that was allocated in the original object.